# R markdown csv file data import

Tags: r, csv, import, r-markdown

I am a begginer of Rmarkdown and have a question when I import the csv file to Rmarkdown. I set the working directory to the folder where the csv file is saved. When I ran the code below in the Rmarkdown, I never imported the file and got the message like "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

````
title: "Test"
author: "AI"
date: "5/9/2021"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)```
````

````
```{r save}
d1<-read.csv("Test5.csv", header = TRUE)```
````

Please help me.

Comment: Try using the full path to the file ... your error is a typical one that points to the path to file being insufficient (rarely a permission thing) ... so I would not bet that u are in the right directory there

Comment: FWIW, an R package that has solved this issue for me is the `here` package: https://github.com/jennybc/here_here

Comment: Make sure the file is in the same directory are the .Rmd file